# Function won't properly add elements of a 2d array?

Tags: c, function, for-loop, multidimensional-array

Here I have a program that prompts the user to input inches of rainfall every month for 5 years. The program has 3 main functions, `inputData`, `printData`, and `sumRain`.

I can't figure out why my `sumRain` function does not properly calculate the sum of rainfall for each year.

My only guess is that it has to do with improper loop usage, but I can't say for sure. Since this is a homework assignment, hints would be more appreciated than actual solutions.

```
#define NUMMONTHS 12
#define NUMYEARS 5
#include <stdio.h>

void inputData();
void printData();
void sumRain();

float Raindata [NUMYEARS] [NUMMONTHS];
char years [NUMYEARS] [5] = {"2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015"};
char months [NUMMONTHS] [12] = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};

int main() {
  char enterData = 'y' ; 
  printf("Do you want to enter precipitation data? \n");
  scanf("%c", &enterData);

  if (enterData == 'y') {
    inputData();
    printData();
    sumRain();  
  }
  else {    
    printf("No data was input at this time \n");
  } 
  printf("Please try the precipitation program again. \n");
  return 0;
}

void  inputData() {
  float rain = 1.0;
  for (int year = 0; year < NUMYEARS; year++) {
    for ( int month = 0; month < NUMMONTHS; month++) {
      printf("enter rain for %d, %d: \n", year + 1, month + 1);
      scanf("%f", &rain);
      Raindata [year][month] = rain;
    }
  }
}

void printData() {
  printf("year\t month\t rain\n");
  for (int year = 0; year < NUMYEARS; year++){
    for (int month = 0; month < NUMMONTHS; month++){
      printf("%s \t %s \t %.2f \n", years[year], months[month], Raindata[year][month]);
    }
  }
}

void sumRain() {
  float sums [NUMYEARS] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
  float zero = 0;

  for (int year = 0; year < NUMYEARS; year++){
    for (int month = 0; month < NUMMONTHS; month++){
      sums[year] = zero + Raindata [year][month];
    }
    printf("%s sum is %.2f \n", years[year], sums[year]);
  }
}
```

Comment: regarding this line: `if (enterData == 'y') {`   shouldn't the program continue if the user entered 'Y`?   Suggest passing the `enterData through the function: `tolower()`  found in the header file: `ctype...h`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: writing a `float` value has two requirements.  1) it must contain a decimal point 2) it must be immediately followed by the letter `f`.  As it is, `1.0` is a `double` value, to make it a `float` value write it as: `1.0f`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what is the purpose of declaring the variable `zero` But in any case the function can be written the following way

```
void sumRain() {
  float sums [NUMYEARS] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

  for (int year = 0; year < NUMYEARS; year++){
    for (int month = 0; month < NUMMONTHS; month++){
      sums[year]  +=  Raindata [year] [month];
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
    printf("%s sum is %.2f \n", years[year], sums[year]);
  }
}
```